# How do I distinguish between a normal install and an upgrade in WIX?

Tags: .net, wix, wix3.5

I have some custom actions that I only want to execute in an upgrade scenario.

I am trying to set some properties, for example "MYPROPERTY"... When I come in via a standard install, I can set them, and an example of that XML is as follows...

```
<Custom Action="SetMyPropertyToOn" After="exampleActionRuuningBeforeThisOne"> (ENABLEMYPROPERTY_CB) AND (NOT ENABLEMYPROPERTY_CB="0") AND (NOT ENABLEMYPROPERTY) AND (NOT Installed)</Custom>
```

It runs in a normal install... I would also like it to run in an upgrade scenario.

Comment: A Major Upgrade or a Minor Upgrade? If you are doing a minor upgrade then Installed would be true and this would evaluate to false.

Answer (score 34):

I use this in all my setups:

```
    <SetProperty After="FindRelatedProducts" Id="FirstInstall" Value="true">
        NOT Installed AND NOT WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED AND NOT WIX_DOWNGRADE_DETECTED
    </SetProperty>
    <SetProperty After="SetFirstInstall" Id="Upgrading" Value="true">
        WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED AND NOT (REMOVE="ALL")
    </SetProperty>
    <SetProperty After="RemoveExistingProducts" Id="RemovingForUpgrade" Sequence="execute" Value="true">
        (REMOVE="ALL") AND UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE
    </SetProperty>
    <SetProperty After="SetUpgrading" Id="Uninstalling" Value="true">
        Installed AND (REMOVE="ALL") AND NOT (WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED OR UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE)
    </SetProperty>
    <SetProperty After="SetUninstalling" Id="Maintenance" Value="true">
        Installed AND NOT Upgrading AND NOT Uninstalling AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE
    </SetProperty>
```

You can then schedule your custom action to only run on upgrades:

```
<Custom Action="NameOfCustomAction" Before="InstallFinalize"><![CDATA[Upgrading= "true"]]></Custom>
```

Comment: Thanks Natalie, I only have one small issue with this. Somehow, I always seem to get into the "FirstInstall" part, and then skipping the rest, even on upgrade... The others always skip.

Comment: Strange, Ive never experienced that. Could you post your log file maybe that would help?

Comment: The properties WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED and WIX_DOWNGRADE_DETECTED assumes the MajorUpgrade element was used.  User defined Upgrade rules may have different ActionProperty names and a minor upgrade wouldn't have these at all.  The OP didn't say what *kind* of upgrade he was doing.

Comment: Point noted @ChristopherPainter, thanks I was not aware of this as at the moment I am only using major upgrades.

Comment: Tested, seems working fine, but when you install not ALL features and launch the installer again to choose the "Remove" option, the "Maintenance" flag is ON during both runs. However I'd expect "Uninstalling" ON for the second run. The "Uninstalling" condition fails because REMOVE <> "ALL", it's equal to a list of installed features instead.

Comment: @NatalieCarr Thanks so much for posting this! I came across it recently and now, years later, it's still valid and exactly what I needed to solve a similar problem.

Comment: I can't understand why Sequence="execute" was added just to RemovingForUpgrade property:

```<SetProperty After="RemoveExistingProducts" Id="RemovingForUpgrade" Sequence="execute" Value="true">```

This seems to be incorrect, because when RemovingForUpgrade property does not get set and this fails the condition check for the old product being removed before the new version gets installed. I removed Sequence="execute" and it all worked well for me. Someone, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to explain that I wanted to use RemovingForUpgrade in my <Condition>

Comment: <Condition Message="Use FORCE=yes parameter to force the upgrade of this version><![CDATA[FirstInstall OR Uninstalling OR RemovingForUpgrade OR FORCE="yes"></Condition> - the <Condition> statement is evaluated at the UI execute sequence, not the InstallExecuteSequence