# Running Custom Action before uninstall or Upgrade

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wix, wix3.5, wix3

I am trying to run a custom action before my application gets upgraded or uninstalled ( Before the files are removed as I have to copy a database file to another directory )

**Problem** - I am able to run it when I uninstall it from control panel but I am unable to do so when I Upgrade it.On upgrading the setup is getting ended prematurely and the old version is also getting removed.

Here is my code -

```
<MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed."/>

<Binary Id="secondAction" SourceFile="..\Migrations\bin\Debug\Migrations.CA.dll" />

<CustomAction Id="secondActionId"
              BinaryKey="secondAction"
              DllEntry="Migrate"
              Execute="deferred"
              Return="check" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
   <Custom Action="secondActionId" Before ="RemoveFiles">(REMOVE~="ALL") OR (WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED)</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: Have a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18531272/how-do-i-distinguish-between-a-normal-install-and-an-upgrade-in-wix  At least, you gave to use `UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE` to detect upgrade scenario

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running before RemoveFiles try running after InstallValidate.  I believe RemoveFiles only occurs on an uninstall.  InstallValidate will occur before the existing product is removed.